# My Application is not responding to the request given by front end and throwing a CORS exception

Tags: java, ember.js, cors, dropwizard

I have created a web service using `dropwizard`.

1. Through this, I am able to create resources, wherein I have created an entity for indexing the document, search request, getting doc by id.
2. By hitting the API in postman I get the desired result.
3. For developing the web application I built the front end using ember.js.
4. But when I send a request to my application I am getting **CORS policy exception.**

   - When I am sending request through postman to `http://localhost:9090`  (`9090` is the port number of my ApplicationConnector) then it is responding to the request.
   - **Now when I send request from origin `http://localhost:4200` (`4200`is the default port number for ember.js) to `http://localhost:9090` it is giving error :**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://localhost:9090/{indexName}/{id} >from origin http://localhost:4200 has been **blocked by CORS policy**: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>    No 'Access->Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So can someone please explain how to resolve this issue and if there is any other way apart from enabling CORS in Dropwizard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS in Dropwizard or serve both the frontend and the API from the same host (hostname and port). Otherwise it's forbidden by [CORS security feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which is enabled by default in all major browsers. Postman does not care about CORS.

Comment: Can you explain how to serve both the front end and the API from the same port ?

Comment: FYI I resolved the issue by enabling CORS in dropwizard application.

Comment: Enabling CORS on server-side should be the preferred way in my opinion. Glad that it worked out for you. Please accept the answer if it helped you.